# Enseigne, étiquette, panneau, panonceau

Tags: vocabulaire

Quelqu'un peut-il m'expliquer quelle est la difference entre *enseigne*, *étiquette*, *panneau* et *panonceau* ?

Comment: Pourquoi indiquer Québec et France dans les tags ? Y a-t-il une raison de penser que l'usage qui en est fait dans ces régions est différent ?

Comment: Les définitions qui sont dans le dictionnaire n'aident pas ?

Comment: Est-ce qu'un [enseigne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/enseigne/29802) qui [tombe dans le panneau](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/panneau/57648/locution) respecte l'[étiquette](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/étiquette/31477)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les explications suivantes concernent le français tel qu'utilisé en France.

- Une « enseigne » est une inscription à l'intention du public et elle est toujours de très grande taille en raison de la nécessité qu'elle soit vue de loin (plusieurs dizaines de mètres), cela parce qu'elle sert à communiquer aux gens qu'à l'endroit où on les trouve il existe, habituellement, un commerce ou bien un lieu où un ou plusieurs individus ont une occupation ou des fonctions particulières (par exemple, « Bureau de Poste »); les personnes responsables pour ce commerce ou les personnes qui s'adonnent à cette occupation placent généralement une enseigne au-dessus de l'entrée du commerce ou du bâtiment dans lequel ils vaquent à leur occupation.
- Une étiquette est aussi une inscription qui, par le passé, était toujours sur un petit bout de papier ou de carton léger (de la taille du timbre poste à celle d'une carte de crédit ou plus grand) et que l'on collait sur quelque chose comme un cahier ou la couverture de protection d'un livre, etc de façon à donner à l'item concerné une identification, ou que l'on attachait à certains objets au moyen d'un bout de ficelle dans le même but (fournir une information sur l'objet, comme simplement, parfois, le nom de l'objet); on se sert toujours d'étiquettes ainsi définies, mais de nos jours on a donné au mot une signification supplémentaire : on l'utilise pour des inscriptions que l'on appose directement sur des dessins comme par exemple des dessins  techniques, cela dans le but de nommer des éléments dans ces dessins.
- Un panneau est encore une inscription plus ou moins brève (un mot ou parfois plus) et d'assez grande taille pour être vu de loin, comme les panneaux de signalisation routière, souvent de pas plus de un à trois mots et qui donnent aux automobilistes sur les routes les informations nécessaires à une conduite convenable de leur véhicules (sécurité, directions); on trouve aussi des panneaux devant les commerces, parfois, mais leurs inscriptions sont plus petites et plus longues que sur un panneau de signalisation routière; de plus, au contraire de ces derniers, ils ne sont pas fixes, c'est à dire fichés sur un piquet planté dans le sol, mais ils sont amovibles (les commerçants les sortent dans la journée pour informer leurs clients potentiels de certaines particularités en ce qui concerne leur commerce puis à la fin de leur journée de travail ils les rentrent à l'intérieur; les panneaux se trouvent dans de nombreuses autres circonstances que celles des commerces et de la circulation routière.
- Un panonceau n'est ni plus ni moins qu'un panneau de taille relativement petite.

Comment: Un panneau peut contenir un long (voire très long) texte, il n'y a pas de raison qu'il soit « bref ». Et pour les les usages techniques d'« étiquette », la langue reste très réticente à l'adoption francisée de l'usage anglais (le mot *tag* est utilisé dans la majorité des cas).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez♦ Disons que dans une majorité des cas le texte est bref; il y aura des exceptions comme pour les assez rares panneau que l'on trouve dans par exemple les sites historiques; mais il n'y a jamais beaucoup de place sur un panneau. En ce qui concerne l'usage de « étiquette » qui a été dernièrement étendu pour signifier (souvent) « *symbole ou nom écrit près d'un élément tel que les parties d'un dessin* », **en particulier en mathématiques**, je n'ai jamais trouvé « tag » ni « tagged » mais toujours « étiquette » et « étiquetté ».

Comment: On peut savoir où ?

Comment: StéphaneGimenez♦ J'ai passé en revue quelques pages mais pour l'instant je ne peut pas trouver un cas de l'utilisation de « étiqueté » tel que je soutiens qu'il existe dans la littérature mathématique.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez♦ C'est un peu une aiguille dans une botte de foin; j'ai cependant un exemple dans quelque chose qui se rapporte aux mathématiques : http://www.careersinconstruction.ca/sites/cic/files/pdf/Essential_skills/utilisation_des_mathematiques_pour_les_metiers.pdf

Comment: Je suis déçu, ce n'est pas un exemple convaincant, ça n'a rien d'une utilisation technique. « Étiqueter » n'a jamais été utilisé, du moins jusqu'au 21e siècle, en mathématiques avec le sens avancé, je ne vois donc pas pourquoi on en aurait soudainement besoin. S'il y a de vraies occurrences quelque part (autre que pour de vraies étiquettes ou dans de mauvaises traductions), je serais intéressé de savoir où.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez♦ Dites-vous bien qu'il n'y a pas de fumée sans feu! Je suis bien d'accord avec la période, il s'agit d'un usage introduit relativement récemment.

Answer (score 2):

"Panneau" est un **terme générique** pour toute plaque servant de support à une inscription. En particulier, les panneaux de signalisation fournissent une information sur la sécurité ou la navigation routières.

Le panonceau est un petit panneau, le plus souvent placé **en complément** d'un panneau principal. Par exemple, pour donner l'étendue d'une interdiction de stationner.

Dans sa signification proche du terme panneau, l'enseigne sert à donner de la **visibilité** à un magasin (le nom du magasin en grand sur le bâtiment). Ce n'est pas nécessairement un panneau (par exemple, une enseigne lumineuse faite de néon) et c'est souvent de plus grande taille qu'un panneau classique.

Une étiquette ne rentre pas dans la même catégorie de taille que les termes précédents. C'est une **petite fiche** ou morceau de tissu attachée à un objet pour donner une information (taille, prix...).

Comment: Un panonceau n'est pas forcément le complément d'un panneau principal. Ce peut simplement être un panneau de petite taille.

Comment: @jlliagre: On est d'accord, mais « petit panneau » est il me semble largement plus fréquent que « panonceau » s'il ne s'agit pas d'une désignation particulière telle que celle décrite dans la question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, c'est vrai. Panonceau est beaucoup plus rare que petit panneau. Mon commentaire était juste là pour préciser qu'il n'était pas dépendant de la présence d'un panneau principal. La similitude phonétique est d'ailleurs le fruit du hasard (l'étymologie de panonceau renvoyant aux plumes alors que celle de panneau renvoie au tissu).

Comment: @jlliagre merci pour l'info étymologique. Je me demandais pourquoi il n'y avait qu'un seul N entre le "a" et le "on". J'ai nuancé ma réponse.